# Lag on real Time server/Client application

Tags: java, windows, connection, client-server, lag

I am creating a real time server-client application, where the server sends some painting orders and the client paints them.I developed the entire App in my Mac. Everything has been working without errors in real time, so I decided to test it on my Windows machine.

After a lot of debugging and tests I have isolated the problem. The server sends every 15ms an order.The behaviour changes dramatically in each environment

**Mac**

The client receives an order with a different response time(Outcome = Real Time App)

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
Calling repaint: 1428155128955//Reception Time different
Calling repaint: 1428155129162
Calling repaint: 1428155129178
```

**Windows**

The client receives multiple orders at the same(Outcome = Lag Application). Up to 5 orders are collected simultaneously

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
Calling repaint: 1428155129524//Reception time the same
Calling repaint: 1428155129524
Calling repaint: 1428155129524
```

I want to emphasis that is **the same runnable jar** on both environments with the same internet connection, I have uploaded two videos to illustrate the problem

MAC Video - real-time https://youtu.be/OhNXdGXoQpk

Windows Video - lag https://youtu.be/OhNXdGXoQpk

I have also conducted a Video of live VisualVM in Windows: https://youtu.be/cRNX4b3rlZk. I do not see anything strange that could explain why the lag occurs but I'm far from being an expert (sorry for the low quality).

In addition I have tried

- increase heap size
- use of special garbage collectors

  ```
  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+AggressiveOpts
  ```

What could be affecting the performance so drastically? Is there a possible solution?

I have no clue, what could be causing the lag.

Thank you in advance

**Update**

After  following @Hannes advice I have sniffed all traffic between server and client, the results are as follow:

The packets arrive at different times. But I don´t know why the packet accumulate(it is a simple TCP connection):

```
 clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
 System.out.println("Arrived: "+ System.currentTimeMillis());
 //paint
```

and are read at the same time.

What troubles me more is why it works in my Mac environment....

I have also tested `Socket.setTcpNoDelay(boolean)` without any improvement

Comment: Sniff the traffic. This will give you the time of the package  arrival. It could be a buffer problem too...

Comment: What is the means of communication? TCP?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I have updated my question.The objective is to send shapes(=String), it is a basic TCP connection

Comment: If you keep sending every 15 ms, how far apart time-wise are the batches of the received messages? Also, do you actually notice any lag beside that indicated by the time measurement?

Comment: Have you tried measuring with `System.nanoTime()` instead?

Comment: The problem is that for some reason it is accumulating responses. The normal behavior is 3-5 response with the same System.currentTimemilis() . On the other hand in the Mac environment every response System.currentTimemilis() is different (real Time). Why ?I have no answer for it ,I find no logical reason...

Comment: @IgnacioFerrero: What I as getting at with the suggestion of using `System.nanoTime()` was that Windows' real time precision is rather coarse, IIRC some tens of milliseconds. Are you actually receiving the 3 to 5 responses with a single read call on the given socket?

Comment: @IgnacioFerrero: Another idea, try turning off interrupt moderation for you NIC.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the delayed send. Try to use [`Socket.setTcpNoDelay(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay%28boolean%29).